# Can I add rows to an excel pandas dataframe to the end of any column and have the index be in order?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe, list

I have an excel file of rankings, I have 9900/10000 rankings due to an error that would not let me get the last 100 values. I need to add rows to the excel DataFrame to complete all 10000 values. I would have tried something ASAP but I really do not want to interfere with the excel file because it took a while to get it.

The dataframe is created like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': name_list, 'WTN': wtn_list, "Dubs WTN":dubs_wtn_list})
df.to_excel("rankings.xlsx")
```

and results in this:
[Start of excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4tTP.png)
[End of excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4GQN.png)

I looked online and saw an append method:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': name_list, 'WTN': wtn_list, "Dubs WTN":dubs_wtn_list})     
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("rankings.xlsx") 
  
sheet = wb.active 

for index, row in df1.iterrows():

    sheet.append(row.values.tolist())
  
wb.save('rankings.xlsx')
```

It did not format properly. Is there a way I could edit the file using python to add a list to the end of the columns and have the index also continue to get it like this:

```
List1 = [Sample,Sample2,Sample3]
List2 = [1,12,20]
List3 = [1,11,12]

#Some way to append lists to the end of columns
```

```
9900 | Sample   | 1 | 1
9901 | Sample2  |12 | 11
9902 | Sample3  |20 | 12
```

Comment: "It did not format properly" How did it not format properly?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are using both pandas and openpyxl. Also if you have all data available this answer is not best and you should just use pd.concat() i.e.

```py
data = pd.concat([df, df1])
with pd.ExcelWriter('rankings.xlsx', mode='w', if_sheet_exists='replace') as writer:
    data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='YourSheetName', index=False)
```

Anyways, if that's not the case:

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': name_list, 'WTN': wtn_list, 'Dubs WTN': dubs_wtn_list})

# Use Pandas ExcelWriter instead of openpyxl in mode `a` i.e. we are appending now, not writing
with pd.ExcelWriter('rankings.xlsx', mode='a', if_sheet_exists='replace') as writer:
    df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='YourSheetName', index=False) # default sheet name is 'Sheet1'
```